# Sorting Options Out of Order

Tags: datatables, yadcf

Using yadcf 0.8.9 and datatables 1.10.10, I have a DataTable with sorting options for Product (as seen at https://sharepointupdates.com/Patches). In Chrome (x64, Windows, current version), the options are out of order ('SharePoint Foundation 2010', then 'AppFabric 1.1'). Internet Explorer 11, Edge, and Firefox (x64, Windows, current version) all show the Product dropdown in the correct alphabetical sort order, which also happens to be the sort order as defined on the page.

```
   yadcf.init(table, [
            {
                column_number: 1,
                data: [
                    {
                        value: 'AppFabric 1.1',
                        label: 'AppFabric 1.1'
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'FAST Search Server 2010',
                        label: 'FAST Search Server 2010'
                    }, [...]
                    {
                        value: 'SharePoint Foundation 2010',
                        label: 'SharePoint Foundation 2010'
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'SharePoint Foundation 2013',
                        label: 'SharePoint Foundation 2013'
                    },
```

I'm looking for what I can do to resolve this issue with Chrome, or why Chrome has a different behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `sort_as: 'none'` for that filter, ([read docs](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/8e071af195106fa702f942373c65164b89ca40ff/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L145))

As to why it happens only in Chrome - I guess its sort function on array is different or its the only browser that try's to sort an array with objects (I guess the others give up from the start)

p.s

Since your value/label got same values you can use a simpler `data` - array of strings, that way you might no need to use the `sort_as`, since browser should be able to sort your array of strings properly